# How to make custom function faster/more efficient?

Tags: python, pandas

I made a function to decile in python like so:

```
ttl = df['total_mrk_vol'].sum()
result = []
for i in df['total_mrk_vol']:
    x = math.ceil(10*df['total_mrk_vol'].loc[df['total_mrk_vol'] <= i].sum()/ttl)
    result.append(x)
    df['total_decile_rank'] = result
```

On larger datasets this takes a long time to complete

Is there a way to make this faster/more efficient?

Comment: How about using `threading` or `asyncio` modules?

Comment: 1st option: try using `for row in df.iterrows` instead of `for i in df['total_mrk_vol']` -- it is much faster.
2nd option: do not iterate over dataframe but use `.apply()` [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/18406890)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Does that do what you want it to?